# How to debug code written for blackberry browser?

Tags: debugging, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I have added code (blackberry geolocation) to a web page for the Blackberry browser.

Without a windows machine how would someone debug code for the Blackberry browser?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what machine you are working on, but running a virtual machine may be an option.
I have used VM Fushion6 with my Mac and it worked great. Plus it has a trial period, so it probably wont cost you anything.

http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/